# Woocomerce API v3. Why categories are not removed from the product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am making a put request to website:https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/27910

```
{
    "id": 27910,
    "categories": [],
    "name": "Вугілля Горіхове Gresco 3 шт. Тест"
    
}
```

but the categories are not cleared and 2 categories come back

```
{
    "id": 27910,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 127,
            "name": "Вугілля",
            "slug": "vugillya108_uk"
        },
        {
            "id": 129,
            "name": "Табак для кальяну",
            "slug": "tabak-dlya-kalyanu182_uk"
        }
    ],
}
```

I have tried setting `force=true` but that doesn't help.